# Why is this Javascript code, failing validation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After trying what you've suggested, this is where I'm at:

```
<script>
    function tick() {
  const React.element = (
     '<div><marquee behavior="scroll" bgcolor="lightyellow" loop="-1" width="100%"> <i> <font color="blue"> <strong>Today is: ${ new Date().toDateString() } and the current time is: ${ new Date().toLocaleTimeString() } </strong> </font> </i> </marquee></div>'
  );
  ReactDOM.render(
  React.element,
    document.getElementById("marquee")
  )
}
setInterval(tick, 1000);

    </script>
```

Now, and I get this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration`

Comment: What do you mean 'failing validation'? What are you trying to accomplish with your code?

Comment: man, was this an exercise in using every outdated deprecated tag in HTML?

Comment: Marquee! Ah, memories...

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I've figured this out, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because

```
const element = ( Today is: { new Date().toDateString()} and the current time is: { new Date().toLocaleTimeString()} )
```

should be this

```
const element = `<marquee behavior="scroll" bgcolor="lightyellow" loop="-1" width="100%"> <i> <font color="blue"> <strong>Today is: ${ new Date().toDateString() } and the current time is: ${ new Date().toLocaleTimeString() } </strong> </font> </i> </marquee>`;
```

Comment: Okay I'll make that change, but it was failing in the html section, like where the marquee ends. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: it is likely that the variables being injected were breaking it, as you weren't injecting them properly.

Answer (score 1):

With the limited information you have provided:

```
function tick() { 
const element = ( 
  {
    "date:": new Date().toDateString(), 
    "time": new Date().toLocaleTimeString() 
  });
  ReactDOM.render( element, document.getElementById("marquee") ) 
  } setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

This code will compile. You can have json keys as words with space like Today is: without quotes. Its highky discouraged to have keys with space.